# Launcher icon is shown in square background Android Tablets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher, android-icons

I have assigned `appIcon` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but the issue is my launcher icon is shown in `Square Grey Background`. I don't want to show icon in square background.

> Can anyone please help me how to remove background from launcher icon?

Regards,

Comment: If you are using AndroidStudio then insert image via ImageAsset

Right Click on app->New->ImageAsset->Select LauncherIcons

Comment: Change the settings according to your needs :D

Comment: Is your image in png or jpeg format?

Comment: @RageshRamesh: It is png

Comment: @DemoMail: I have followed your steps but it still shows launcher icon in square background

Comment: My original icon does not have any background

Comment: @MustansarSaeed When Configure Image Asset dialog displays, select shape as none and try again..  may be you will get the result

Comment: @DemoMail: Yes I have selected none but still have the same result.